# Does Spotlight normally index links in ~/Applications?

Tags: spotlight, homebrew, macvim

I have installed [MacVim](https://code.google.com/p/macvim/) through [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/), and this resulted in an alias in ~/Applications that points to /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.3-66/MacVim.app.

Unfortunately MacVim does not show up in Spotlight searches. Is this normal?

Comment: Related question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/23653/can-i-make-a-symlink-to-a-app-folder-in-applications-directory-show-up-in-spo

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's actually a symlink and not an alias. Spotlight indexes symlinks to files that are treated as system files, but it doesn't show them in the GUI. It does show aliases though, so you could just *command-option-drag* /usr/local/Cellar/macvim/*/MacVim.app to /Applications from Finder.

Or convert the symlinks to aliases:

```
brew linkapps; find ~/Applications -type l | while read f; do osascript -e "tell app \"Finder\" to make new alias file at POSIX file \"/Applications\" to POSIX file \"$(/usr/bin/stat -f%Y "$f")\""; rm "$f"; done
```

Or if you use Alfred, it can be set to include applications in /usr/local/Cellar in the default search results.

Comment: After running the script MacVim is now visible in the results (categorized as a document)

Comment: Alfred does not index aliases in /Applications, so I had to add /usr/local/Cellar in Alfred's preferences.